# rewrite nginx so that resources started resolving from the root

Tags: nginx

I have the following url:
`localhost/web-app/some/path/here`
How can I configure nginx to treat `/web-app/` part as `/`? What I mean is that it starts searching for `some/path/here` resource from its document root and not from the `web-app` folder. Currently I have the following configuration:

```
listen       80;
server_name  app.client;
root   webclient/build/dist;
index  index.html;

location ~ /rest/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Comment: `location /web-app/ { alias /; }`. `root` must be an absolute path.

Comment: @Deadooshka, thanks! I tried `localhost/web-app` but it didn't work, returned `404`. What do you mean by _`root` must be an absolute path_?

Comment: i mean line 3 `root   /webclient/build/dist;` with forward slash

Comment: actually my root is defined as a path relative to the ngxinx executable, it looks like this `root   ../../Projects/app/app-web/src/main/webclient/build/dist;`. Is it a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, either :

- Nginx is compiled a way than the `--prefix` is the beginning of the absolute path that your root directive resolves too, for instance :

  `$ nginx -V [...] --prefix=/path/to [...]`

You could then use :

```
server {

    root /path/to/my/;

    location /foo {
        alias ./docs;
    }

}
```

Then it will alias to `/path/to/my/docs`;

- There's no such thing then as `/` in the alias directive will resolve as your filesystem root, you will have to provide the full directory path instead.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I don't have `--prefix configured` (nginx -V showed `--prefix=` without path specified), so I specified the full path to directory starting from `/` filesystem root.